# Default console in ConEmu

Tags: conemu, git-bash

I have git bash setup as a predefined task (task #1). But when I open ConEmu it defaults to cmd console, how do I change the default console to git bash?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the settings (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), select 'Startup'. This allows you to select a single task using the third option, 'Specify named task'. You can use the other options to specify multiple tabs to open on startup.

[image: Startup Options Dialog]

**How to launch from command line \ shortcut \ script**

You can also make a shortcut using the `/cmd` command line switch:

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /cmd PowerShell
```

Replace `PowerShell` with whatever you named your task. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/ConEmuArgs) is a document listing all of the command line options. Note that if you run this while ConEmu is already running it will just open a new tab in the current window. This is usually the desired behavior but this behavior can be overridden using the `-new_console` and `-cur_console` switches (depending on your current setup).

**How to add task bar jump list items**

If you are using Windows 7 or higher, you may also be interested in looking at using the jump list to select a task to startup. This can be done in the 'Main' -> 'Task bar' options page. Check the 'Add ConEmu tasks to Task bar' box and press 'Update Now!'.

[image: Task bar options page]

Comment: BTW, your ConEmu build is very old...

Comment: Just checked and it appears to be the latest in the stable branch.

Comment: That is not true. "Stable" branch stalled in 2012.

Comment: On Github the stable branch is older than my version so I cannot disagree with that statement. However, when I use the auto update feature in the program, switching to either of the other two branches will tell me that an update is available (neither of which actually match the latest Github releases though). Also, I've had this update the stable branch in the last 6 months (which is how I ended up with this version) so it hasn't been completely dead. There is definitely a disconnect between the Github versions and the versions pushed out within the application.

Comment: Your statement is funny because [official github mirror](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) shows version 140923 which is obviously fresher than was shown on your screenshots.

Comment: Also https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/StableVsPreview

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the SourceForge repository: http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/files/Stable/ . Github doesn't have a stable branch (only master, daily and preview branches). Not sure which is more official but it looks like SF is more complete at least since it's the only one with a stable branch. Regardless, if you are using the stable branch and you have auto updates on then it seem that you should be at version 131225 (which is only about 8 months old and was probably the current preview version when the GitHub site was created).

Comment: As I said before, stable branch stalled in 2012: http://conemu-maximus5.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ConEmu/version.ini And on all mirrors of course.